# XML фигуры в Android

Tags: xml, android

Добрый день,

Есть ли альтернативные программы для создания xml-фигур (кнопок, рамок и тд), кроме редактора в Eclipse? Получается в нем, пишем xml - смотрим, а хотелось бы рисовать, а файл генерится сам.

Уважаемые обитатели hashcode, подскажите, какие способы, примочки и программы вы используете для кнопок и тд.? Photoshop + res/drawable/ ? NinePatch? XML? alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intellij IDEA там есть встроенный редактор, который генерит XML'ки

Правда, я лично, предпочитаю все равно врукопашную... Ни один редактор не может заменить т.н. WYSIWYG верстку.

**Update**

Открываете xml файл лейаута и шлепаете на таб "Design". Выглядит как то так... 
[image: JetBrains designer]

Comment: Гм, а где в IDEA этот самый генератор `xml shape drawable`?

Comment: присоединись к вопросу, хоть тоже все делаю руками но любопытно

Comment: Ну так это `layout editor`, а автор вопроса спрашивал про генератор `shape drawable`.

Comment: Не понимаю тогда что значит генератор `shape drawable`...

Comment: А вы вопрос вообще читали, прежде чем отвечать? :)

> альтернативные программы для создания xml-фигур (кнопок, рамок и тд)
>
> хотелось бы рисовать, а файл генерится сам

То есть автору вопроса хочется, чтобы можно было в чём-то, похожем на графический редактор, рисовать, например, кнопки, задавать градиенты, границы, закругления углов и так далее, а на основе всего этого генерировался бы `xml shape drawable` с нужными значениями.